# Sluggish Android Studio Start up

Tags: android-studio

I have Android Studio 3.0.1 with latest JDK installed on my i7 (4th Gen) dual core Win10 machine, 16GB RAM, 850 Pro 512GB SSD. But even with this beastly configuration, when double clicking on the Android Studio icon to launch the application, the software feels very sluggish in starting up. Takes approx. 15-20 odd seconds to just start up and then do the Gradle build of last opened app, which takes another 30-40 seconds.

Have set the vmoptions & gradle.properties to use -Xms2g and -Xmx4g along with parallel build, offline gradle execution and configureondemand.

Is there a way to drastically improve this performance when I have such a good machine configuration, probably tweaking some other Windows / Android Studio level parameters? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It start in seconds only because of that configuration.It takes few minutes to start in my laptop with 8gb ram.
So the time you mentioned seems pretty good.